# Return many rows on a plsql Oracle10g

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, plsql

I'm doing a little project and I need to do a plsql to return many rows.

I have someting like:

```
Table(id, data1, data2, from)
```

And the user gives me the value of from and I have to return all that.

The SQL is easy:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE from = dataIntroduced
```

But, I don't know how the plsql can return that.

I read about collections but I think is not what I need

Comment: Why can't you simply issue your `SELECT` (without involving plsql)?

Comment: because is a class project and they ask that way... i'm not confortable too with this because i can do views and selects as you say but they ask me to do in a procedure. the problem is i been searching oracle docs since 2 days now and i'm not able to find nothing about this.

Comment: here are a few solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101033/how-to-return-multiple-rows-from-the-stored-procedure-oracle-pl-sql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of return select data from PL/SQL is using Oracle table functions.  Below is an example where the line `SELECT * FROM table_a where test_a = par1;` should be replaced by your select statement + change the table name.

```
Create table Table_a
(test_a varchar2(1))
/

insert into table_a
values('a')
/

create or replace package test_package as
TYPE col_table_1 is table of TABLE_A%ROWTYPE;
function test_plsql_table(par1 varchar2) return col_table_1
  pipelined;
end;
/

create or replace package body test_package as
  function test_plsql_table(par1 varchar2) return col_table_1
    PIPELINED as
    cursor temp_cur is
      SELECT * FROM table_a where test_a = par1;
  begin
    for cur_rec in temp_cur loop
      pipe row(cur_rec);
    end loop;
  end;
end;

/

SELECT * from TABLE( test_package.test_plsql_table('a'))
/
```

Comment: You should not use `;` **and** `/` for regular DDL (it's correct for PL/SQL, but your `create table` and `insert into` will be executed twice by SQL*Plus (because `/` re-runs the current buffer)

Comment: Quite right, sorry.  I will make the amendments now.

Comment: Good lord.  I knew Pipeline functions were a thing but hadn't ever thought to use them this way.  You're awesome and I have to go question some life choices.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible approach is to return a cursor.  Something like

```
create or replace function get_emps_in_dept( p_dept_in IN number )
  return sys_refcursor
is
  l_ret sys_refcursor;
begin
  open l_ret
   for select *
         from emp
        where deptno = p_dept_in;
  return l_ret;
end;
```

You can then call that in SQL*Plus by declaring a host variable (most front-end languages will treat a function returning a `SYS_REFCURSOR` very much like a `SELECT` statement that returns a cursor)

```
SQL> variable rc refcursor;
SQL> exec :rc := get_emps_in_dept( 30 );

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1601        300
        30

      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1251        500
        30

      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1251       1400
        30

      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2851
        30

      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81       1501          0
        30

      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81        951
        30


6 rows selected.
```

You can return a collection, either all at once or pipelined, but that requires more code to  create and maintain the objects.  I love pipelined table functions if you need to embed PL/SQL logic in the query itself that would be difficult to follow in SQL.  But they're overkill if you just need to run a simple query and return the results.